# UPDATE database after approval from admin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

`I have a web page where testimonials are displayed. I want to display only those testimonials whose "status" is "1" in the database. How do I update my database column named "status" from "0" to "1" straight away after the admin click on update . I am using AJAX also.

```
<tr align='center'>
<?php
include ('includes/connect.php');
$query1= "SELECT* from testdata ORDER BY 1  DESC ";
                                         $run= mysql_query($query1) ;

                                         while 
                                            ($row =mysql_fetch_array($run)){

                                                $Id=$row['0'];
                                                $name=$row['1'];
                                                $company=$row['2'];
                                                $designation=$row['3'];
                                                $email= $row['4'];
                                                $message=$row['5'];




                                       ?>

<td> <?php echo $Id?>  </td>
<td> <?php echo $name; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $company ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $designation ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $email ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $message ?> </td>


<td > <form method ="post" action= "update.php"> <input type ="submit" value= "approve" name ="approve"></input></form>  </td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
















<tr align='center'>
```

```
<td> <?php echo $Id?>  </td>
<td> <?php echo $name1; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $company1 ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $designation1 ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $email1 ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $message1 ?> </td>


<td > <input class='action' type ="submit" value= "update" name ="update"></input> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: _"How do I code my update file?"_ -> This will involve code from both `PHP` i.e. Server side and JavaScript i.e. Client side. I do not know much about PHP but for JS, you are almost there. You do need to call your PHP method via `Ajax` on `change` event of drop down. What is the blocker right now?

Comment: update.php file is not updating database which can set the value fron "0" to "1" in status column of database

Answer (score 0):

just change your query

```
"select * from testdata where status =".$_POST['data1'] "
```

and in your script change the $(this).attr('id') to $(this).val()

```
  $('#approve').change(function(){
       var data1 = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({ / / ajax block starts
        url: 'update.php', // 
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
         data1: data1 
       },

     success: function(data) {

        }
     });
```

Comment: php is throwing error after changing query like this

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\project_test\view.php on line 45

Comment: can you update your new code , because i can't able to find which is line no 45 can you specify that line

Comment: i have uploaded my new code , help me with ajax and where to add it

Comment: and this is sql code  , 
   <?php      
    if(isset($_POST['update']) ){
                                                   
                                                    
                         $query3="UPDATE testdata SET Name= '$name2' , Company='$company2, Designation='$designation2, Email='$email2, Message='$smessage2 , status = '1' WHERE Id= 
                         '$approval'";